# Postfix forwarding all email regardless of restrictions

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to set up Postfix to relay mail only if it's coming from localhost, AND only if it's going to a certain domain. However, as soon as I've specified a relay server, everything (except local deliver) is going there. I was thinking I had restrictions wrong, so I've finally gone down to "reject everything" and it still goes through. Wondering if `mynetworks` bypasses everything, I undefined `mynetworks`. Still relays everything.

At this juncture, `postconf -n` gives:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = host.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, localhost
myhostname = host.domain.com
mynetworks =
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = domain.com
relayhost = [mailserver.domain.com]:587
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

I was initially trying something more like this (showing just what's different):

```
mydestination = host.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, localhost
myhostname = host.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_auth_destination reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_auth_destination reject
```

I'm at a loss. No transport table. Postfix 2.11.0 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: What do you want to do to other emails from localhost? Reject?

Comment: Deliver local or relay to domain.com (obviously this is censored :) ), reject all others. As far as I can tell, the current setup should reject *everything*, and that's not happening, so I'm deeply puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally got working. The key was `default_transport = error`, so that anything not matching the relay just gets bounced. Thanks @Marki555 for getting me to think beyond the smtpd settings.

```
default_transport = error
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mydestination = host.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, localhost
myhostname = host.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]/128
relay_domains = domain.com
relay_transport = smtp
relayhost = [mailserver.domain.com]:587
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_auth_destination reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_auth_destination reject
```

Another good postfix debugging hint: a local bounce message (i.e., relay refused immediately) still has the name of the relay host in it, even though the relay host wasn't touched!

I also looked into `master_service_disable = inet`, but enough stuff handles local mail sending by connecting to localhost:25 that it wasn't really practical.

Answer (score 3):

Relay server in postfix terminology is a server to which postfix will deliver all non-local email (for example postfix in internal company network would define company's main email server as its relay, so it won't try to contact destination servers at all). This is for sending email and is controller by the **`relayhost`** directive.

Postfix knows which domains are his by configuration of the **`mydestination`** directive. Domains in this list will be delivered locally (if they have correct MX record).

Hosts in [**`mynetworks`**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) are allowed to send email from everywhere to everywhere. Therefore you should set here only network you trust (localhost only, or internal network). It is said that postfix relays email from these hosts to the internet. This is the default setting, which is set in `smtpd_relay_restrictions` (or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` before v2.10) having the `permit_mynetworks` value. If you remove `permit_mynetworks` entirely from postfix config, then `mynetworks` parameter won't do anything.

Directive **`relay_domains`** controls for which non-local domains postfix accepts email from the entire world. This is typically used when your postfix is backup MX for some domain.

---

So in your case the configuration should have `mynetworks` empty (if empty is not possible, use some internal IP which is not used in your network like 10.10.10.10) **OR** remove `permit_mynetworks` from `smtpd_client_restrictions`.

```
relay_domains = domain.com
mydestination = host.domain.com localhost
relayhost = [mailserver.domain.com]:587
```

Comment: So postfix always completely trusts `mynetworks`? What is the purpose of the `permit_mynetworks` directive then? postfix is running on `host.domain.com`. Mail for localhost stays there. Other mail for `domain.com` should be relayed via `mailserver.domain.com`. All other mail should be rejected.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that is the default behaviours, but can be changed. I have updated the answer with more info on `mynetworks`.

Comment: One more comment: locally submitted email (not going via TCP port 25) will still be probably allowed.

Comment: Thanks for that thought! That is almost certainly the issue, as everything I'm trying to tweak is "smtpd_xxx_restrictions." I'll dig into the docs with that in mind and see if I can figure it from there.